# OSCOLA BibLaTeX footnotes missing commas before pinpoints

Tags: biblatex

I have found what I think is a bug in either BibLaTeX or the OSCOLA style. When pinpoint citing a journal article (and perhaps other types of sources) after citing a book chapter, the footnote for the journal article does not always have a comma separating the article start page from the pinpoint page.

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=oscola,        citereset=chapter,     ibidtracker=true,          
   backend=biber,        babel=hyphen]{biblatex}
 \addbibresource{test.bib} 
\title{Test Document}
\begin{document}


 This is a reference to a book chapter.\autocite[]{Chapter}

This is a reference to a journal article, which should have a comma before the second page reference.\autocite[116]{Article}   

\end{document}
```

And the required bibliography file:

```
@Incollection{Chapter,
author = {Author, Chapter}, 
title = {Book Chapter}, 
booktitle = {Edited Collection}, 
editor = {Editor,Book}, 
publisher = {Publisher}, 
address = {}, 
pages = {}, 
year = {2014}, 
edition = {},
}

@Article{Article,
author = {Author, Article}, 
title = {Journal Article}, 
journal = {Academic Journal}, 
volume = {30}, 
number = {1}, 
pages = {114}, 
year = {2014}, 
location = {}
}
```

The second citation should read "114, 116" but (at least on my system), it reads "114 116". The comma is missing. How can I restore it?

Comment: Hmm, I get "114, 116" at the end of the last citation as one would expect. (I run `biblatex 2.9a` and Biber 1.9 and `oscola` says `2014/05/22 v1.4`) Is your system up to date? Do you have any other code that could influence the citation bibliography? Did you run the very code above or does the error only occur in a larger document?

Comment: The relevant command should be `\postnotedelim`, but it defaults to `\addcomma\space` as expected, maybe something changed that in your document.

Comment: I get the wanted result. Perhaps you are using older versions of `biber` and/or `biblatex`?

Comment: Can you add any more information that could help us discover the behaviour you are experiencing, or was the problem resolved by an update? If you do not provide additional and follow-up information, I'm afraid, your question is not really solvable and might therefore be closed.

Comment: The problem was resolved by an update. I had manually installed OSCOLA into a local repository (in ~/Library/texmf on my Mac). When I deleted those files, the problem went away. I think OSCOLA may not have been part of distributions some years ago. I also updated from TeXLive 2013 to 2014, and that may have helped.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an outdated version of the software, the problem was resolved by an update.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I voted to close this question then.